# Prevent button being focused (VueJS, Buefy)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, buefy

Just want to prevent one of my buefy button to be focused when i click on it :

Code of the button :

```
<b-button class="button-rounded" type="is-success" icon-right="film" rounded />
```

Not focused :
[image]

Focused :
[image]

In my use case other design i add on the button are getting cleared by the focus, i want to prevent any focus when clicking on the button. I'm using VueJS 2 with Buefy (Bulma)

Any idea ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
<b-button tabindex="-1" class="button-rounded" type="is-success" icon-right="film" rounded />
```

do the trick?

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Comment: And what if together with the triggered function you trigger the blur() on the button?

`<b-button @click="this.blur()" class="button-rounded" type="is-success" icon-right="film" rounded />`

Comment: sorry i forgot to respond, this was not working too :/